# Error: object Logger is not a member of package com.typesafe.scalalogging

Tags: scala, maven, logging

I am trying to use `scala-logging` in our project. Even after adding dependency in pom, Logger is not getting resolved. I am using scala 2.13.
Following is the error message thrown.

```
object Logger is not a member of package com.typesafe.scalalogging
```

Code:

```
import com.typesafe.scalalogging.Logger
val logger: Logger = com.typesafe.scalalogging.Logger(this.getClass)
```

pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.typesafe.scala-logging</groupId>
   <artifactId>scala-logging_3</artifactId>
   <version>3.9.5</version>
</dependency>
```

I have tried the code as updated above. Any pointers on how this can be resolved? Thanks.

Comment: It seems you are using the **Scala 3** version of the artifact rather than the `2.13` one.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Thing is, Scala 3 libraries are usable in Scala 2.13 code - provided you have newer Scala 2.13 and `-Ytasty-reader` flag enabled. In sbt it works though it might require `("organization" %% "library" % version).cross(CrossVersion.for2_13Use3)`.